# Ruby: type() global method

Tags: ruby

I'm just curious what the type() global method is.

I used it

```
a = 1
puts type(a)
```

and just got "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a deprecated equivalent of [`class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001012), and it’s gone in 1.9.

```
>> send :class
=> Object
>> 1.type
(irb):5: warning: Object#type is deprecated; use Object#class
=> Fixnum
```

Comment: The method has been removed in Ruby 1.9, so they weren't kidding about the deprecation.

Answer (score 1):

> Deprecated synonym for Object#class.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/type